# How to change the picture in a userform if clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change a picture in a userform to an "active format" when it is clicked and then when another picture is clicked the picture that was previously clicked goes back to a "dormant format" and the new  picture that has been clicked is now an "active format". This is to show the user which menu they are currently on.

I have been trying to use the following code to do this but I cannot seem to get the pictures to return to the "dormant format" when the other picture is clicked. The code is also very lengthy so if there are an suggestions on how to reduce the length that would be helpful as I have 8 menus in the userform.

```
    '----------------------------------------------------------Menu 0 Button
Private Sub Home_Bttn_Click()

 Home.MultiPage1.Value = 0

 If Home.MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then

    Home_Bttn.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectRaised

    '----------------------------------------------------------Changing button to active and setting others to Dormant
    'Activated
    Home_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Home_Bttn_Activated.jpg")
    'Dormant
    Create_Protocol_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Create_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    Create_Summary_Report_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Create_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    Review_Summary_Report_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Review_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    Add_Report_Template_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    Add_to_Database_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_to_Database_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    User_Agreement_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\User_Agreement_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    Email_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Email_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    Mobile_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Mobile_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
    'Title
    Menu_Title.Caption = "Home"    
 End If    
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------Menu 1 Button
Private Sub Create_Protocol_Bttn_Click()

 Home.MultiPage1.Value = 1

 If Home.MultiPage1.Value = 1 Then

     Create_Protocol_Bttn.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectRaised

     '----------------------------------------------------------Changing button to active and setting others to Dormant
     'Activated
     Create_Protocol_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Create_Protocol_Bttn_Activated.jpg")
     'Dormant
     Home_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Home_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     Create_Summary_Report_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Create_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     Review_Summary_Report_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Review_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     Add_Report_Template_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     Add_to_Database_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_to_Database_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     User_Agreement_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\User_Agreement_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     Email_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Email_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     Mobile_Bttn.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Mobile_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
     'Title
     Menu_Title.Caption = "Create Protocol"    
 End If    
End Sub
```

Editied Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private buttArrN As Variant, pictArr As Variant, dormArr As Variant

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
'User form start up focus on multipage 1 and then focus on username field
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0
Me.Login_Error_Message.Visible = False
Me.Username_fld.SetFocus

buttArrN = Array(Me.Home_Bttn.Name, Me.Mobile_Bttn.Name, Me.Email_Bttn.Name)
'Me.Create_Protocol_Bttn.Name, Me.Create_Summary_Report_Bttn.Name, Me.Review_Summary_Report_Bttn.Name, Me.Add_Report_Template_Bttn.Name, Me.Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn.Name, Me.Add_to_Database_Bttn.Name, Me.User_Agreement_Bttn.Name)

pictArr = Array(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Home_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Mobile_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Email_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")

'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Create_Protocol_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Create_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Review_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_to_Database_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\User_Agreement_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")


dormArr = Array("F:\Automation\Report Creation Wizard\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Home_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Mobile_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Email_Bttn_Activated.jpg")
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Create_Protocol_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Create_Summary_Report_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Review_Summary_Report_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Add_to_Database_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
'        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\User_Agreement_Bttn_Activated.jpg")

End Sub

Private Sub Login_Bttn_Click()
'Execute login in module code
CheckUser

End Sub

Private Sub Home_Bttn_Click()
   testChangePicture Me.Home_Bttn
   Menu_Title.Caption = "User Login"
End Sub

Private Sub Mobile_Bttn_Click()
    testChangePicture Me.Mobile_Bttn
    Menu_Title.Caption = "Mobile Contact Menu"
End Sub

Private Sub Email_Bttn_Click()
    testChangePicture Me.Email_Bttn
    Menu_Title.Caption = "Email Contact Menu"
End Sub

'Private Sub Create_Protocol_Bttn_Click()
'    testChangePicture Me.Create_Protocol_Bttn
'    Menu_Title.Caption = "Create a Protocol"
'End Sub
'
'Private Sub Create_Summary_Report_Bttn_Click()
'    testChangePicture Me.Create_Summary_Report_Bttn
'    Menu_Title.Caption = "Create a Summary Report"
'End Sub
'
'Private Sub Review_Summary_Report_Bttn_Click()
'    testChangePicture Me.Review_Summary_Report_Bttn
'    Menu_Title.Caption = "Review Summary Report"
'End Sub
'
'Private Sub Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Click()
'    testChangePicture Me.Add_Report_Template_Bttn
'    Menu_Title.Caption = "Add a Report Template"
'End Sub
'
'Private Sub Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn_Click()
'    testChangePicture Me.Add_Calbration_Certificates_Bttn
'    Menu_Title.Caption = "Add Calibration Certificates"
'End Sub
'
'Private Sub Add_to_Database_Bttn_Click()
'    testChangePicture Me.Add_to_Database_Bttn
'    Menu_Title.Caption = "Add to Wizard Database"
'End Sub
'
'Private Sub User_Agreement_Bttn_Click()
'    testChangePicture Me.User_Agreement_Bttn
'    Menu_Title.Caption = "User Agreement"
'End Sub

Private Sub testChangePicture(but As Control)
 Dim c As Variant, pos As Long, i As Long

 pos = Application.Match(but.Name, buttArrN, False)
 Me.Controls(buttArrN(pos - 1)).Picture = LoadPicture(pictArr(pos))
 For Each c In buttArrN
    If c <> buttArrN(pos - 1) Then
       Me.Controls(c).Picture = LoadPicture(dormArr(i))
    End If
    i = i + 1
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

I prepared it for only three buttons, but I think the code can easily be extended of all controls existing in your project.

Firstly, create the next variables of the module level (on top of it, in the declarations part):

```
Option Explicit

Private buttArrN As Variant, pictArr As Variant, dormArr As Variant
```

Then, put this code in the `Form_Initialize` event. You must extend the arrays according to your buttons number:

```
  buttArrN = Array(Me.Home_Bttn.Name, Me.Create_Protocol_Bttn.Name, Me.Add_Report_Template_Bttn.Name)

  pictArr = Array(ThisWorkbook.path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Home_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
        ThisWorkbook.path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Create_Protocol_Bttn_Activated.jpg", _
        ThisWorkbook.path & "\UI\General Buttons\Activated\Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Activated.jpg")

  dormArr = Array(ThisWorkbook.path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Home_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
        ThisWorkbook.path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Create_Summary_Report_Bttn_Dormant.jpg", _
            ThisWorkbook.path & "\UI\General Buttons\Dormant\Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Dormant.jpg")
```

Each of your buttons to change their picture `Click` event will call a single sub, as following:

```
Private Sub Home_Bttn_Click()
   testChangePicture Me.Home_Bttn
   Me.Repaint
End Sub

Private Sub Create_Protocol_Bttn_Click()
    testChangePicture Me.Create_Protocol_Bttn
    Me.Repaint
End Sub

Private Sub Add_Report_Template_Bttn_Click()
    testChangePicture Me.Add_Report_Template_Bttn
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

And the called sub will look like this:

```
Private Sub testChangePicture(but As Control)
 Dim c As Variant, pos As Long, i As Long

 pos = Application.Match(but.Name, buttArrN, False)
 If pos = 0 Then MsgBox but.Name & " button is missing from ""buttArrN"" array!": Exit Sub

 If Not FileExists(pictArr(pos - 1)) Then _
        MsgBox "The path to the active picture """ & pictArr(pos - 1) & """ is wrong!": Exit Sub

 Me.Controls(buttArrN(pos - 1)).Picture = LoadPicture(pictArr(pos - 1))

 For Each c In buttArrN
    If c <> buttArrN(pos - 1) Then
       If Not FileExists(dormArr(i)) Then _
            MsgBox "The path to the dormant picture """ & dormArr(i) & """ is wrong!": Exit Sub
            Me.Controls(c).Picture = LoadPicture(dormArr(i))
    End If
    i = i + 1
 Next
End Sub

Private Function FileExists(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
      FileExists = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
    On Error GoTo 0: Err.Clear
End Function
```

I was too lazy to build paths for real pictures, so the code is not tested on the real environment. I just tested the fact that `testChangePicture` sub is able do identify the caller button.

Edited: I added a new function (`FileExists`) which checks if the pictures path is correct. If not, it stops the code and sends an elocvent message. I also added an new line `Me.Repaint` in all buttons click event. In my case, the code works without it, but in yours doesn't. It was simpler to force the form repainting, then finding the reason...

Important is to understand how the code works and take care to properly fill the three arrays. **They must be filled in the same order for each involved control**!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your in depth explainaintion, unfortunatly there is an error saying that there is a type mismatch (Error code 13) on this line "pos = Application.Match(but.Name, buttArrN, False)" any Ideas on why this might be?

Comment: Did you create the private variables at the form module level (on top of it)? I mean `Private buttArrN As Variant, pictArr As Variant, dormArr As Variant`... And the piece of code loading those array (in Form_Initialize event)?

Comment: Yes I have added them as private variables above the initialize Private Sub, and then I have also loaded the arrays as you suggested in the initialize Private sub

Comment: What you say, sorry, is impossible! If you did not make a mistake in `buttArrN` loading, the function `Match` does not retrieve an error if it finds a match. Try, please, put the next code before the line returning an error: `Dim El as Variant`. Then the next code: `For Each El in buttArrN`    'Debug.Print El`   `Next`. Then press Ctrl + G and see what is returned in Immediate Window. Do you see there the name of the button you pressed?

Comment: "For Each El In buttArrN" line is giving the same error 13 as above? Nothing appears in the immedite window :(

Comment: So, you did not load anything in `buttArrN` array... Try simply the next line: `Debug.Print Ubound(buttArrN)`. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the code you use now. Not delete the existing one. Try to structure it in the way I did above. Maybe, you will understand where is the mistake, or I will immediately see what you wrongly did. I can stay no more the 15 minutes...

Comment: I cannot stay too long... Please add in your form Initialize event, just after `buttArrN = Array(Me.Home_Bttn.Name, Me.Mobile_Bttn.Name,....)` the code `Debug.Print Ubound(buttArrN): Stop`. The code will stop here. What does `Debut.print` return in Imediate Window? But be fast please. I cannot stay anymore. It is late in my country and tomorrow I need to wake up very early...

Comment: nothing appears in the window, it says that the array is empty?

Comment: How did you "succeed" to create `Private Sub Home_Initialize()`? What is this? It should be `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`!  Independent of your form name! That procedure is there for nothing! Your code does not use it at all!

Comment: Home is the name of the userform

Comment: Do you use Excel? Open the form, whatever it is named and double click on it. In an area where no control exist. What event do you see? Please copy it here. The event must not be modified by you. It is created by Excel!

Comment: The Immediate window now prints 9, but the error still persists?

Comment: Only now you come from your home... Please comment this last code line and run the code. It should work as expected now. I would never could imagine that you changed the natural event name... :) If you also made some other mistakes, I would suggest you to look at the paths you filled in the arrays. If the code works as expected, please tick the check box to the left answer side. In this way somebody else asking for something similar, will know that this is the accepted answer. And learn something...

Comment: Appologies, this made complete sense to me to change the userform name. The file cannot be found, there is now an error on "Me.Controls(c).Picture = LoadPicture(dormArr(i))"

Comment: You simple wrongly filed the path of the picture. Please check if what you filled in the array is correct. I would also like to suggest you to fill only three buttons, VERY CAREFULLY and see that the code works. Only after that fill all the arrays button by button and check after each such a step. If you correctly fill the paths, the code will work perfect. I tested it! Now look to that specific button you tested and the code stops! Now I must go to bed. If still problematic, I will be able to assist you tomorrow... By!

Comment: @Calum Burns: Hello! Did you succeed in making the code to work as you need?

Comment: Hey, I managed to get it to change the images but not in the way I intended. When I press one of the buttons all of the buttons change to the activated state which is the opposite of what I want it to do. I also get an error when I press some of the buttons which states that the subscript is out of range? when I debug it brings up the line " Me.Controls(buttArrN(pos)).Picture = LoadPicture(pictArr(pos))". Any Idea Why? I tried reversing the arrays but this did nothing.

Comment: This is impossible, if you correctly filled the arrays! The code will load the picture of the `pictArr` for the pressed button and the pictures from `dormArr`. The code is so clear from this point of view... Why didn't you follow my suggestion, to carefully fill the arrays for only three buttons and six pictures path? And do the rest, step by step, after seeing that the logic  is OK... Please edit your question, let your code as it is and post what you built starting from my code. FOR ONLY THREE BUTTONS (6 PICTURES PATHS).

Comment: @Calum Burns: But, this time, I would like  you to be a little fast. I am working at a project and I cannot wait too long for your reply... In order to shorten the debugging time, please do only what I would suggest you to do. Otherwise, I do not have time to loose for experiments...

Comment: I have edited the code, I commented out the rest of the buttons as you suggested but the error still exsists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209397/discussion-between-calum-burns-and-faneduru).

Comment: @Calum Burns: Still alive? :)

Comment: yes, It is all sorted, woking perfectly now! Thank for all your help

Comment: @Calum Burns: If if works as you need, we usually vote the answer up and what it would be more important is to tick the code answer left side check box in order to make it the accepted answer. If somebody else would need something similar, he will see which answer has been marked as accepted...

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't have your images, I just made an example with a bunch of different ones.

My example has 3 buttons on a form (`Btn1, Btn2, Btn3`) and uses 6 Images (`red_on.bmp, red_off.bmp, blue_on.bmp, blue_off.bmp, green_on.bmp, green_off.bmp`)

The code in `UserForm_Initialize` Pre-loads the images and activates `Btn1`

Buttons are Activated by passing the name of the button to `ActivateButton`

```
Private MenuControl As Object

Private Sub Btn1_Click()
ActivateButton "Btn1"
End Sub

Private Sub Btn2_Click()
ActivateButton Me.ActiveControl.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Btn3_Click()
ActivateButton "Btn3"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If MenuControl Is Nothing Then Set MenuControl = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' MenuControl.Add <Button>.Name, Array(<Button>, <Button State 1>, <Button State 2>, <Button Group>)
MenuControl.Add Btn1.Name, Array(UserForm1.Btn1, LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\red_on.bmp"), LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\red_off.bmp"), "Main")
MenuControl.Add Btn2.Name, Array(UserForm1.Btn2, LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\blue_on.bmp"), LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\blue_off.bmp"), "Main")
MenuControl.Add Btn3.Name, Array(UserForm1.Btn3, LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\green_on.bmp"), LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\green_off.bmp"), "Main")

ActivateButton TargetName:="Btn1"

End Sub


Private Sub ActivateButton(TargetName As String)
Dim Key As Variant
Dim Group As String: Group = MenuControl.Item(TargetName)(3)

For Each Key In MenuControl.Keys
    If MenuControl.Item(Key)(3) = Group Then
        If Key = TargetName Then
            MenuControl.Item(Key)(0).Picture = MenuControl.Item(Key)(1)
        Else
            MenuControl.Item(Key)(0).Picture = MenuControl.Item(Key)(2)
        End If
    End If
Next Key

End Sub
```

The above code is similar to that of the example below but has the ability to make groups of buttons.

[Example Workbook](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=19478511128571525570)

Comment: Nice way of `Dictionary` use... But, if the dictionary is specifically loaded only with buttons to be controlled, why the buttons group would be needed? Am I missing something?

Comment: Anyhow, I never imagined that `LoadPicture` function can be accepted by a dictionary...

Comment: The Group was an after-thought. The question says there are several menus and I thought that there might be groups of buttons that need to toggle interdependently from each other. Nested tabs or radio-button groups etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommed a slightly different approach

**Pros**:

1. You do not have to depend on a hardcoded path for the images
2. You can distribute your workbook without having to worry about images
3. Your code *drasssssssssticaly* reduces!

**In Action**

[image]

**Logic**

Place relevant number of image controls in your userform and set their visible property to False. Upload all images from `...\UI\General Buttons\...` path and store it in these image controls.

Now all you have to do is use a **one liner** to load the relevant image. No need of `LoadPicture` anymore. For example

```
Image1.Picture = Image3.Picture
```

In the above example, I created a userform and placed 3 image controls and a togglebutton as shown below

[image]

And the code that I used is

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Image1.Picture = Image2.Picture
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        Image1.Picture = Image3.Picture
    Else
        Image1.Picture = Image2.Picture
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: [From garfield.com/terms-of-use](https://garfield.com/terms-of-use) _3. ... We regret that we do not grant permission to copy, download, distribute or otherwise use any of the materials from this Site without the advance, written consent of Paws._

Comment: @chrisneilsen I have sent an email to their legal department. Waiting for their permission, if they ask me to remove it, I will. BTW I already have alternate images of my cats ready in case I do not get the permisssion. It is just that I love Garfield :)